# How to stop text from moving when making smaller window

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am self-learning how to code basic websites and Im stuck for some time on this:

I want to make my text justify with width 750px somewhere on the left side of website and when reducing window to move the text not all the way to the left side but stop it somewhere next to the clickable buttons on left, eg. 300px. When window smaller than 300px from left + 750px text width + 100 px from right make the text width smaller, eg. 500px.

How do I do that? Thank you very much for any help.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Arial";
        src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arial&display=swap);
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Courier New";
        src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+New&display=swap);
      }
      body {
        background-color: white;
      }
      h1 {
        position: absolute;
        letter-spacing: -10px;
        left: 30px;
        top: -35px;
        font-size: 85px;
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      h2 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        top: 95px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: "Courier New";
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      h3 a {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        margin-top: 350px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: "Courier New";
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
      h4 a {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        margin-top:  649px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: "Courier New";
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
      h5 a {
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
        margin-top:  676px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: "Courier New";
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
      p {
        position: absolute;
        right: 100px;
        margin-top: 350px;
        max-width: 750px;
        font-family: 'Courier New';
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: justify;
      
      /* Media queries for responsive design */
      @media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
        p {
        right: 100px;
        }
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
        p {
          top: 350px;
          left: 900px;
        }
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 1536px) {
        p {
          top: 350px;
          left: 600px;
        }
      }

            @media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
        p {

        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
        p {

        }
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
        p {

        }
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
        p {

        }
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      function updateTime() {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = addZero(d.getUTCHours());
        var m = addZero(d.getUTCMinutes());
        var s = addZero(d.getUTCSeconds());
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " UTC";
      }
      function addZero(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
          i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;
      }
      setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="updateTime()">
    <h1>OSAA</h1>
    <h2 id="time">00:00:00 UTC</h2>
    <h3><a href="#">enquire [x]</a></h3>
    <h4><a href="#">about us</a></h4>
    <h5><a href="#">projects</a></h5>
    <p>to enquire about our services, please write us an email with your full name and a short description and/or files that might help with the solution.<br><br><a href="mailto:osaa.contact@gmail.com" style="color: inherit; text-decoration: none;">osaa.contact@gmail.com</a><br><br>we will get back to you promptly.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, welcome to SO! Using `position: absolute` for all your page elements is fundamentally wrong for responsively sizing websites. Especially when combined with *fixed unit (px)* size and positioning values. Search online for *website structure* (e.g. [MDN: Document and website structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure)) and *responsive design* (e.g. [MDN: Responsive design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)). You will keep running into brick walls otherwise.

Comment: Running your code I see two main sections: 1) left - a sidebar and 2) right - main content. The sidebar is divided into a *logo section* (with clock) and an *action section*, while the main content section is divided into a *text section*, *contact section* and an *outro section*. All can easily be constructed with *Flexbox* or *CSS Grid*, fully responsive with minimal use of `@media` queries. Do yourself a favor, do the reading and toy with the concepts. Then redo the site... One more search for you: *css holy grail layout*.